# Update position of fixed element on scroll is slightly behind in IE and Firefox only

Tags: javascript, css, requestanimationframe

I've created a fiddle for this question: https://jsfiddle.net/alinnert/wcz7qm9u/

In this fiddle there are two elements:

- An ordinary `<p>` (`position: static;`)
- A fixed `<div>` (`position: fixed;`)

I'm using `requestAnimationFrame()` to update the position of the fixed element. And I try to position it at the exact same Y coordinate as the paragraph. This is just a simplified example to demonstrate the issue.

It looks totally fine in Chrome. But in IE, Edge and Firefox the position is slightly "behind" when I'm scrolling. After I'm finished scrolling the position is correct. But it seems the rendering after the calculation has been made happens too late.

Is there an explanation to how and why that happens? And is there something I can do about that in said browsers?

There are those parallax scrolling scripts around the web. They work the exact same way. Is it just that you don't notice that effect with parallax scrolling?

---

*Edit* for better understanding of the problem: I scrolled the example and took a screenshot at the same time.

[image: screenshot of position fixed problem]

This is what it looks like for a very short period of time. If I scroll in the other direction the fixed element is visible above instead of below the paragraph.

Comment: your fiddle fails to demonstrate any fixed elements - nevermind, I see it now

Comment: Perhaps browsers have a different default font-family and size? Adding them to the CSS https://jsfiddle.net/wcz7qm9u/1/ seems to make both firefox and Chrome identical

Comment: @JaromandaX not really. I'm talking about the effect that it seems that in FF and IE the fixed element moves slower (or rather later) than the *static* content when you scroll the page. If you're not scrolling the position is always correct, in every browser.

Comment: Oh. I didn't see any effect at all I  any browser

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature introduced in FF 46.

Basically this can also happen in Chrome and other browsers (Although in Chrome it only happens a) sometimes and b) for just one frame out of 1000.)

The `scroll` event is not really synced with the real rendering of the scroll. The oldschool scroll event was indeed synced with the visual scroll. But especially for mobile it was hard to have a performant `scroll` rendering that is synced with JS including the `scroll` event.

The main solution was to decouple the scroll rendering from the main thread. As you know JS is executed in the main thread and therefore this results in the fact that JS (main thread) and visual scrolling (a special composition thread) are out of sync.

You might be able to workaround this by simply `fixing` everything and than animating the transform x property. Maybe also hooking into `wheel` event might help. (Using `wheel` partially destroys the performant async nature of the scroll rendering (this is why passive event listeners, where introduced).

You can read more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/02/smoother-scrolling-in-firefox-46-with-apz/

Comment: You're talking about the `scroll` event. I'm not using that but `requestAnimationFrame` instead. I'm not sure if your answer is correct in this context. But I've noticed that it's a lot better in new Firefox versions that use the Quantum rendering engine. So I guess it's just a result of "slow" engines.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I was talking about the `scroll` event, while you where talking about rAF. The answer is still correct. It is about the different threads. JS is executed in the so called main thread (which includes both scroll event and rAF) the scroll animation by the browser is executed in a different thread. This is why it is not in sync with the event or even the paint in FF. If you read the articles I posted, you should understand. Your guess isn't really right. In FF 45 you would have noticed a jank but the scroll event as also your rAF was totally in sync with the scroll painting.

Comment: So, technically it's impossible to solve this problem, and in recent engines, it's just small enough to be almost unnoticeable, right?

Comment: I do know about the basic differences between main thread and render thread. Both articles just don't mention rAF, that's why I wasn't able to draw that connection.
So to really solve this problem there needs to be an API that provides access to the browser's paint thread, right? You wouldn't happen to know if that's what Project Houdini is about? I only remember it "gives you more control over how elements are being rendered".

Comment: Project houdini is an umbrella term for a lot of technologies and yes there are some idea to solve this problem through some houdini APIs. here is an example: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/proposal-animationworklet-a-primitive-for-scroll-linked-and-high-performance-procedural-animated-effects/1710 but there are more ideas